# Managing Multiple Forms with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have two forms on a landing page. One is to capture leads (first form), the other form displays a webpage in a lightbox based upon the data a user enters (second form).

If a user hits return, both forms are submitted simultaneously. That is not ideal. I am using the following jQuery code to get the closest form to submit. This code enables the lightbox to open, however, both forms still submit, and therefore nothing populates in the lightbox. Ultimately the user is redirected to the webpage that is supposed to display in the lightbox.

```
<script>
$("second-form").closest("form").submit();
$("input[type=text]")
.keydown(function(e) { 
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        $(this).closest("form").submit(); 
});
</script>
```

html code for forms:

```
 <form name="form" id="second-form" action="website" method="get" target="_self">    
 <input type="text" id="zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" name="search" minlength="5" maxlength="5" size="12" pattern="\d{5}" title="A Zip Code should consist of five numbers" required />
 <input type="submit" value="Go" id="button" class="button">
 </form>
```

Comment: Normally a form only submits on enter if it has focus. You should figure out why yours are. Show some HTML.

Comment: instead of closest('form') why not use parents('form') since the input field will always be a child of the form tag

Comment: @isherwood updating with html. none of my forms use autofocus.

Comment: @PAPAFRESH switching to parents form makes no difference in this case

Comment: You have a syntax error (missing ID hash): $("second-form")....

Comment: @isherwood good catch-- unfortunately it doesnt change anything. ive tried to use jquery to validate the other form and prevent default if fields are invalid. but that is not working either

Comment: @user1049946 using parents() is faster than using closest() see this link: http://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/37 -- also this: http://jsperf.com/jquery-closest-faster-than-parents --

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    }
});
```

...you need to prevent the event's default action or all forms are submitted.

Also, why are you submitting `second-form` on page load with this line?

```
$("second-form").closest("form").submit();
```

Comment: unfortunately this method doesnt work. i cant get the lightbox to open using this snippet.

Comment: This method -does- do exactly what you asked for.  You didn't ask to open a lightbox, you asked to prevent dual form submission.  There's nothing about a lightbox in your code.